# A complex transformation of a data set in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
dictionary = {'Year': [1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987], 'Wteam' :[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'lteam': [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] }
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

    Wteam   Year    lteam
0    1      1985    9
1    2      1985    10
2    3      1986    11
3    4      1986    12
4    5      1987    13
5    6      1987    14
```

I need to create a new data frame in the following format :

```
team values   predicted_value 
1985_1_9            1
1985_2_10           1
1986_3_11           1 
1986_4_12           1
1987_5_13           1
1987_6_13           1
```

The values of my new data frame should be in this format "year_Wteam_lteam". How do I do that in pandas. The predicted values column is always 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
final['team values'] = pdf['Year'].astype('str') + '_' + pdf['Wteam'].astype('str') + '_' + pdf['lteam'].astype('str')
final['predicted_value'] = 1
```

Comment: Instead of string what if I want the numbers as integers?

Comment: @user3796494: it doesn't make sense to concatenate an integer with an underscore.  `1985_1_9` has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do without creating a new dataframe is:

```
In [15]: pdf['team values'] = pdf.apply(lambda row: str(row['Year'])+'_'+ str(row['Wteam'])+'_'+str(row['lteam']), axis=1)

In [16]: pdf['predicted_value'] = 1

In [17]: pdf.drop(['Wteam','Year','lteam'],axis=1,inplace=True)

In [18]: print pdf.head()
  team values  predicted_value
0    1985_1_9                1
1   1985_2_10                1
2   1986_3_11                1
3   1986_4_12                1
4   1987_5_13                1
```