# looping and transformation in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
dictionary = {'Year': [1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987], 'Wteam' :[9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6], 'lteam': [ 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 14] }
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

    Wteam   Year    lteam
0    9      1985    1
1    10     1985    2
2    11     1986    3
3    4      1986    12
4    5      1987    13
5    6      1987    14
```

I need to create a new data frame in pandas that has the following rows and columns

```
Season_value   result
1985_1_9          0
1985_2_10         0
1985_3_11         0
1985_4_12         1
1985_5_13         1
1985_6_14         1
```

The logic for forming the new table is as follows:
I must loop through each row in the `pdf` table and then if the W_team value is greater than l_team then the first column value in my `new data frame`  should be **"year_lteam_wteam"** and the result value should be zero.

If the value of W_team value is lesser than l_team then the first column in my `new data frame` should be **year_Wteam_lteam** and the result column should be zero.

a referral [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916543/a-complex-transformation-of-a-data-set-in-pandas/28916671?noredirect=1#comment46091299_28916671)

Comment: Are you restricted to looping through the dataframe?  In other words, are you interested in computing the same output directly from the dictionary?

Comment: Also, you wrote for both cases that the result value should be zero -- did you mean it should be one for the second case?

Comment: @jedwards yes I want the output from the data frane. in the first case it should be zero and in the second case it should be one.

Comment: @jedwards - can you also explain how np.where works in this context( in the solution). it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

- use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign values to `pdf['result']` based on a condition. In `np.where(cond, 0, 1)`, `cond` is a boolean array-like. `np.where` returns a new array with the same shape as `cond` which takes the value 0 where `cond` is True, and 1 where `cond` is False.
- use `.min()` and `.max()` to reorder `Wteam` and `lteam`.
- build the `Season_value` column as [Mostafa Mahmoud showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28916671/190597).

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def tostr(series):
    return series.astype(str)

dictionary = {'Year': [1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987], 'Wteam' :[9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6], 'lteam': [ 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 14] }
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
pdf['result'] = np.where(pdf['Wteam'] > pdf['lteam'], 0, 1)
pdf['min'] = pdf[['Wteam','lteam']].min(axis=1)
pdf['max'] = pdf[['Wteam','lteam']].max(axis=1)

pdf['Season_value'] = tostr(pdf['Year'])+'_'+tostr(pdf['min'])+'_'+tostr(pdf['max'])

print(pdf[['Season_value', 'result']])
```

yields

```
  Season_value  result
0     1985_1_9       0
1    1985_2_10       0
2    1986_3_11       0
3    1986_4_12       1
4    1987_5_13       1
5    1987_6_14       1
```

Comment: can you also explain how np.where works in this context.